# Recursion function to calculate the sum of squares in a sequence (and output the process)

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

```
int SeriesToOne(int n) {
   if (n == 1) {
       cout << "(" << 1 << "*" << 1 << ") = ";
       return 1;
   }
   cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") + ";
return (n * n) + SeriesToOne(n - 1); }
```

Hey so I'm writing a program thats supposed to calculate the sum of squares in a sequence using recursion.

I'm writing two functions, one that calculates it going from 1 to N and one that calculates it going from N to 1, and outputting the process. The above code is the function that I wrote for N to 1, but I'm having a lot of trouble with going from 1 to N.

I don't know how to properly write out the base case and get to that base case without adding a second argument to the function (the assignment specifies one argument).

If anyone could help me out, that'd be awesome! And sorry if I didn't format this post or put it in the wrong section, first time poster.

Comment: You don't have tail recursion here (so the tag is out of place). But this actually is good for you: why not do the recursive call before printing?

Comment: Before printing the line before last? Would i not need to change the base case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as you need to know the value of n inside the recursion function because of the base condition, you can either declare variable as global or you can pass it to function in every call like below:

```
int SeriesToN(int n, int N) {
    if (n == N) {
        cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") = ";
        return n * n;
    }
    cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") + ";
    return (n * n) + SeriesToN(n + 1, N); 
}
```

Then call the function like follow if n = 4:

```
SeriesToN(1, 4);
```

This should solve you problem. Happy coding!

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you very much. Is there no way to use one function with one argument (without using a global variable)?

Comment: I don't think there have any other way.

Comment: I posted a way with (practically) one argument. But true, one needs two in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is  implementation in javascript.

```
function SeriesToN(n, initialCount){
       if(!initialCount){
                initialCount  = 1;
              }
       if(initialCount === n){
            return n * n ;
         }

        return (initialCount * initialCount) + SeriesToN(n , initialCount + 1)

     }

     SeriesToN(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int SeriesToN(int n, int limit = -1) 
{   
    // catch edge cases
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "(1 * 1) = ";
        return 1;
    } else if (n <= 0) {
        cout << "n should be >= ";
        return 1;
    }

    // the actual action
    if (limit == 0) 
    {
        cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") = ";
        return n * n;
    } else if (limit == -1) // handling one argument input
    {
        limit = n - 1;
        n = 1;
        cout << "(" << 1 << "*" << 1 << ") + ";
        return (1) + SeriesToN(2, limit - 1);         
    } else
    {   
        cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") + ";
        return (n * n) + SeriesToN(n + 1, limit - 1); 
    }
};


int main()
{
    cout << SeriesToN(10);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << SeriesToN(3);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << SeriesToN(2);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << SeriesToN(1);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << SeriesToN(0);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << SeriesToN(-1);
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

```
/* output:
(1*1) + (2*2) + (3*3) + (4*4) + (5*5) + (6*6) + (7*7) + (8*8) + (9*9) + (10*10) = 385
(1*1) + (2*2) + (3*3) = 14
(1*1) + (2*2) = 5
(1 * 1) = 1
n should be >= 1
n should be >= 1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good implementation for a recursive function, but it do the job:

```
int SeriesToN(int n) {
    static int N = n;
    static bool firstTime = true;
    if (n == N && !(firstTime)) {
        cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") = ";
        return (n*n);
    }
    else {
        if (n == N) {
            firstTime = false;
            n = 1;
        }
        cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") + ";
        return (n * n) + SeriesToN(n + 1);
    }
}
```

It counts from 1 to n, as you wished, with just one argument and without any global variables.

Answer (score 0):

i am for you! just you need to do tail and head recursion in a single frame. that's it. :D

you can use the following code snippet:

```
int SeriesToOne(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;

   cout<<endl<<n+" : "+(n * n);


   int sum = 0;
   sum += n * n;
   sum += seriesToOne(n-1); // due to loose overhead when n will become 0.

   cout<<endl<<n+" : "+(n * n);

   sum += n * n;

   return sum; // return the total sum we get after two functionality (tail-head recur.)
  }
```

edit: i am not friend of c++, ignore all the syntax mistake if anything had!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is

- do this piece of work (print the `n` term), then the remaining work (from `n-1` down to `1`)

and what you want is

- do the initial work first (from `1` up to `n-1`), then this piece of work (print the `n` term)

Save the recursion's result in a variable (and leave the `=` bit for `main`, which is responsible for printing the result):

```
int SeriesToOne(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "(" << 1 << "*" << 1 << ")";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "(" << n << "*" << n << ") + ";
    int sum = (n * n) + SeriesToOne(n - 1);
    return sum;
}
```

and then you can change the work order (and move the `+` output):

```
int SeriesFromOne(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "(" << 1 << "*" << 1 << ")";
        return 1;
    }
    int sum = (n * n) + SeriesFromOne(n - 1);
    cout << " + (" << n << "*" << n << ")";
    return sum;
}
```